# Efficiently load multiple ad hoc NHibernate entities with cache support

Tags: .net, nhibernate, caching, criteria

I need to efficiently load a large number of entities based on a list of ad hoc IDs. Unfortunately it doesn't look like the 2nd level cache is checked first when making `Restrictions.In(Projections.Id(), ids)` criteria queries.

I guess I'm looking for something similar to `ISession.Load` that takes a collection of IDs (instead of just one) and only execute an IN query for entities that can't be found in either the 1st or 2nd level caches. If nothing like this exists then what's the easiest way to check the two caches manually without resorting to reflection?

Comment: What is wrong with Session.Load?

Comment: @DarrenKopp Calling `Load` on each ID will issue multiple database queries. I want a single query that skips already cached entities.

Comment: Not necessarily. Load will return a proxy, but will not issue a query. A query is executed when something on the object is accessed, but until it is accessed, it will not query the database. NHibernate also has query batching, so you could call load a thousand times, and with a batch size of 200, only get 50 queries to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Darren Kopp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/77/darren-kopp)'s comment is absolutely right, batching automatically handles this provided you remember to use `ISession.Load` instead of `ISession.Get` and you don't touch any of the proxy objects until you've finished fetching them all.

However I thought I'd share another novel solution I came up with for environments that don't have lazy loading or batching enabled. By subclassing the `DefaultLoadEventListener` class and returning null from the `LoadFromDatasource` method it's possible to load an entity if it exists in the 1st or 2nd level caches without touching the database. It's then a simple matter of fetching the missing entities in a single IN query and weaving them into an ordered collection of results.

```
static IList<T> LoadAll<T>(this ISession session, params object[] ids)
    where T : class
{
    var results = new T[ids.Length];
    var uncachedIds = new Dictionary<object, int>();
    var helper = new LoadHelper();
    for (var i = 0; i < ids.Length; i++) {
        var id = ids[i];
        var evt = new LoadEvent(id, typeof (T).FullName, false,
                                (SessionImpl) session);
        helper.OnLoad(evt, LoadEventListener.Get);
        var entity = (T) evt.Result;
        if (entity != null) {
            results[i] = entity;
        }
        else {
            uncachedIds.Add(id, i);
        }
    }
    if (uncachedIds.Count > 0) {
        var entities = session.CreateCriteria<T>()
            .Add(Restrictions.In(Projections.Id(), uncachedIds.Keys))
            .List<T>();
        foreach (var entity in entities) {
            var id = session.GetIdentifier(entity);
            var index = uncachedIds[id];
            results[index] = entity;
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

Here's the very simple `LoadHelper` class that does the heavy lifting:

```
private class LoadHelper : DefaultLoadEventListener
{
    protected override object LoadFromDatasource(LoadEvent evt,
                                                 IEntityPersister persister,
                                                 EntityKey keyToLoad,
                                                 LoadType options)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var entities = adhocIds
    .Select(session.Load<TEntity>)
    .ToList();

var notloaded = entities
    .Where(entity => !NHibernateUtil.IsInitialized(entity))
    .Select(session.GetIdentifier)
    .ToList();

// we don't need the resultset, we just load it
// so the proxies hit the cache instead of the DB
session.CreateCriteria<TEntity>()
    .Add(Restrictions.In(Projections.Id(), notloaded))
    .List();

return entities;
```

Comment: This makes sense in theory but doesn't work across sessions. `Session.Load` returns an uninitialized proxy if the entity is in the 2nd level cache and not the 1st level cache.

Comment: @NathanBaulch nice refactoring. I am no expert in NH 2nd lvl caches b ut i thought it caches queries and its result. How can it know that another query (Restrictions.In with differnt ids) returns the same results? i dont think it analysis the semantics of the query